# PrimeFaces 3 TabView with Extra Whitespace

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a number of tabs and one is a search tab.  When the search button is pressed a new tab is displayed with the results of the search.  When the new tab is displayed there is a number of whitespace lines then the data table of results.

With the help of firebug I have determined that the whitespace seems to be the other tabs.

Also, after the results come up if I go to a different tab then back to the results tab the whitespace is not rendered.  Thought the dynamic tag would take care of this.

This does not occur on other tabs in my project when the activeIndex is NOT used.

[image]

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" activeIndex="#{bean.activeTab}" dynamic="true" cache="false">
   <p:tab id="data" title="Data">
      <h:form> ... </h:form>
   </p:tab>      
   <p:tab id="search" title="Search">
      <h:form> 
         ... 
         <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.doWork}" update="tabs,growlForm:growlMesg">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.activeTab}" value="2" />
          </p:commandButton>          
      </h:form>
   </p:tab>
   <p:tab id="results" title="Results" rendered="bean.showResults">
      <h:form> ... </h:form>
   </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CSS issue.  The project was just upgraded from PrimeFaces 2.2.1 to 3.0.1.

There were jQuery UI Theming CSS tags for the TabView which was altering the behavior due to re-implementation of the widget in the new version.

The upgrade to the TabView in question.

> Reimplemented as a native PrimeFaces widget instead of using jQuery
>   UI's tabs widget.  Reference: [PrimeFaces Migration Guide](http://wiki.primefaces.org/display/General/Migration+Guide+to+3.0)

So all I had to do is remove all the jQuery UI Tabs theming tabs in the CSS and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is a CSS issue, but you can fix this with a simple inline-block.

```
/* Fix p:tabView v3.0.1 */
div.ui-tabs ul.ui-helper-clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Some others suggestions for you:

```
/* Anothers cool css for p:tabview */
div.ui-tabs div.ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 8px 4px 2px;
}

div.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav {
    background: none;
}

div.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A8A8A8 !important;
    background-color: #74ffcc;
}

div.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A8A8A8 !important;
    background-color: #54dfac;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
}

div.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected.ui-state-hover {
    background-color: #54dfac !important;
}

div.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-hover {
    background-color: #64efbc !important;
}
```